# /dev/sda: unrecognised disk label

Tags: partitioning, kubuntu

I have 3 1TB HDDs, that I'm trying to format and mount in linux. I can`t create partitions delete or format that drives, but they are completely clean, i already deleted windows (I disabled windows fast boot). In windows disks work perfectly.

In GParted (GUI) I see:

partition - unallocated
file system - unallocated
warning - unrecognised disk label

When im trying to mount drive, i get this :

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda, missing codepage or helper program, or other error
```

Here are some screenshots from fsdisk and lsblk (Talking about drives sda, sdb, sdd) :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SE8d.jpg

When I try to create partitions using the fdisk /dev/sda command, it says that the partitions have been created, but in fact they are not created

UPD :
I use Kubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Here are some screenshots from GParted :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGd8D.jpg
When I try to create a partition table, it just loads and nothing happens, you can see it in one of the screenshots

UPD 2.0 : After using mkusb i still can`t use partition tools, but this time i tried to format drive also in KDE partition manager, and i revieved following errors :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpAH2.jpg

Data from the drives does not matter, just help me to make able to use them.

Comment: Use gparted and post the results in the question with edit. What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 5 days of surfing the internet i found solution on russian-speaking stackoverflow :
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/982988/unrecognised-disk-label-%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%8E-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA

As it says there, the problem is in the Gigabyte GA-970A DS3P motherboard, all problems are due to the default disabled IOMMU setting, without it, UNIX operating systems start to work poorly on this motherboard. After enabling this setting, all problems disappeared.

Comment: +1+1; Thanks for sharing your solution :-)