# Fixing , /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell mount issue

Tags: partitioning, firefox, filesystem, snap, mountpoint

I installed Firefox as a snap and it set my partition's mount point to **, /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell**. Now, I'm trying to remove the snap installation of Firefox, and it will not completely allow me, failing at this step:

```
Remove data for snap "firefox" (2211) (unlinkat /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell/nl_BE.dic: read-only file system)
```

How can I fully remove Firefox and safely clear this mount point without damaging anything?

Answer (score 1):

from:

[lsblk: root partition mounted on / and /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1431815/lsblk-root-partition-mounted-on-and-var-snap-firefox-common-host-hunspell)

try:

snap disconnect firefox:host-hunspell